# How to remove the css rule "body overflow:hidden" automatically

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, adblock

In some web pages entering with adblock installed is added in the body the "overflow:hidden" css style, preventing the scroll of a website.

Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Website</title>
  </head>
  <body style="overflow: hidden;">
    Some long article content
  </body>
</html>
```

I have to manually edit in Chrome web inspector to remove each time, which is annoying.

I would like know I could make this removal permanent or detect via a chrome extension or adblock rule to remove it or maybe via a direct javascript, etc.

UPDATE: Using tampermonkey chrome extension, probably I could reach my goal. I did the following script without result (the page seems reload or load some javascript and I cannot remove properly the body overflow hidden):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         InvestingRemoveScrollBodyBlocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remove body overflow hidden
// @author       Ángel Guzmán Maeso <angel@guzmanmaeso.com>
// @match        https://*.investing.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    setTimeout(function(){

        var bodyWeb = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        console.log(bodyWeb);
        bodyWeb.style.overflow = "visible !important";

    }, 4000);

})();
```

Comment: Maybe injecting a CSS rule to override this via extension would help. For example body{overflow: auto! important;}

Comment: I think you're talking as a user of adblock. This is then not a programmer's question. Please contact adblock.

Comment: You can't specify !important in a direct property assignment. You can do document.body.style.cssText = 'overflow: visible !important';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this script tool [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

To override overflow

```
body {
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

The script that will work with TamperMonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         InvestingRemoveScrollBodyBlocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @description  Remove body overflow hidden
// @author       Ángel Guzmán Maeso <angel@guzmanmaeso.com>
// @match        https://*.investing.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330252/how-to-remove-the-css-rule-body-overflowhidden-automatically
    document.body.style.cssText = "visible !important";
})();
```

Comment: I use `auto` rather than `visible`. When I tried `visible` it didn't work on some sites.

Answer (score 13):

You can add a [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) filter rule with a [:style() operator](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#style) to override this:

```css
*##html,body:style(overflow: visible !important;)
```